# Move files to new folderif string matches

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm trying to go through a number of folders and check their contents.
If one or more of the files inside matches any of the strings in a given list, I would like to move those files to a new folder. I already have the new folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

find /path/to/sourcedir -type f | grep "string1\|string2\|string3" | while read f
do
  mv "$f" /path/to/destination
done
```

If you have many strings you can skip  `"string1\|string2\|string3"` and
use  `grep --file=file_of_patterns.txt` where `file_of_patterns.txt` is a textfile containing the strings you want to match (one per line)

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer with code! I'll give it a try!